# Logarithm, Just need help understanding what this question is asking. Not looking for an answer.

Tags: logarithms

In my foundations of computing class, we were given a logarithm question which i don't quite understand.
This is the question.

Given the logarithmic table values of the numbers x and y
are ax and ay respectively, and that antilog(ax) = x and
antilog(ay) = y then what does x * y equal in terms of ax
and ay?

I'm just not quite sure what it's asking and would appreciate some guidance.

I'm not sure how to format it properly

Comment: Ok no problem, give me a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are given that
$$
\operatorname{antilog} a_x = x \\
\operatorname{antilog} a_y = y
$$
and are asked to express $x \times y$ in terms of $a_x$ and $a_y$. What you need to know is that
$$
\operatorname{antilog} a = b^{a}
$$
where $b$ is the base of the logarithm. Now,
$$
x \times y = \operatorname{antilog} a_x \times \operatorname{antilog} a_y = b^{a_x} \times b^{a_y}
$$
and I'll let you do the rest, using the basic properties of exponentials and the definition of $\operatorname{antilog}$.

Comment: Ok great, thank you.